# How do I delete multiple kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

How do I delete multiple kubernetes namespaces with a single command.

Comment: `kubectl delete ns foo bar test demo`. Or `kubectl delete ns -l labelname=value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl delete namespace $(kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep <wildcard> - )
```

For example :

```
kubectl delete namespace $(kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep my_namespace_* - )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash if you have more than one. It's also I nice example of a bash script with a function executing a multiple command from a list.

```
#!/bin/bash

execute_command() {
    (
        NAMESPACE=$1
        kubectl proxy &
        kubectl get namespace $NAMESPACE -o json |jq '.spec = {"finalizers":[]}' >temp.json
        curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @temp.json 127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/finalize
    )
}

for f in `kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep <namespace-filter>*`
do
    echo "Printing Each Entry in the list  - $f"
    execute_command $f 
done
```